# How to create a link in datatables cell

Tags: jquery, datatables

We are using datatables in a generic way.
Here is how we configure it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC 
 "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script>
    function renderCell(nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
        $(nTd).html('<a href="example.com/download">download</a>');
    }

    $GLOBAL_VARS = {
        aoColumns: [{
             'mData':'alias',
             'fnCreatedCell': renderCell
        }, {
             'mData':'description',
             'fnCreatedCell': renderCell
        }],
        iDisplayStart : 0,
        iDisplayLength : 20,
        iDeferLoading : 67,
        sAjaxSource : 'ressources.json'
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/datatables/generic-config.js"></script>
...
</head>
<body>
 <table id="table_managed_by_datatables">
 <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Alias</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><![CDATA[foo]]></td>
      <td><![CDATA[-]]></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- other trs here... -->
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

With the above code, the cells in the HTML table (managed by Datatables) appear empty.

However, if we replace the `renderCell` function by its version below, all cells now contain ">>download".

```
function renderCell(nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
    $(nTd).html('>>download');
}
```

Why does the html code isn't parsed ?

**jQuery 1.9**
**Datatables 1.9.4**